# Version property working fine but not being saved in Couchbase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, couchbase

We are developing an API server with spring boot, and we are using Couchbase as database.
We have an entity that has the following property:

```
@Version
@Field("version")
private long version;
```

The goal of this property is to handle CAS issues when saving an instance to couchbase. This is working fine, however, I don't see that property when I take a look at the Couchbase panel (the stored document doesn't have it). How is that possible? Shouldn't that version be stored as a property of the json?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm speculating, but it's possible that it's using Couchbase's built-in CAS functionality. (See: https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.6/concurrent-mutations-cluster.html). Couchbase does not store CAS value in the document itself; it's stored as metadata.